# Input text selection not working properly on double-click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When double-clicking on a html page most browsers select the word you double-click on (or the paragraph you triple-click on). But it is not working properly on my html page specially for input field.

Comment: Add more information, with sample code, and may be on plunker / jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="abc" id="abc" name="xyz" ondblclick="this.select()" value="">
```

you can Selet the value of input field by using `ondblclick="this.select()"`